# How to combine the value of two separated columns to one?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------+-------------------+
| id | col1  |       col2        |
+----+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | one   | the first number  |
| 2  | two   | the second number |
| 3  | three | the third number  |
+----+-------+-------------------+
```

Now I want this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------+-------------------------+
| id | col1  |          col2           |
+----+-------+-------------------------+
| 1  | one   | one: the first number   |
| 2  | two   | two: the second number  |
| 3  | three | three: the third number |
+----+-------+-------------------------+
```

---

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE mytable t1
  SET col2 = ( SELECT CONCAT(col1, ": ", col2) AS newcol
                 FROM mytable t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id )
```

But my query doesn't work, it has this error:

> **#1093** - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try:

```
 UPDATE mytable t1
 SET col2 = CONCAT(col1, ": ", col2);
```

Comment: Heh ... Really I don't know why I made it complicated for myself ..! Thanks +1

Comment: its ok. Sometimes another pair of eyes help. And If you didnt explain your question so well I wouldn't solve it so fast. ;)